# paypal sandbox merchant services tab can not find

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created Paypal sand box account but it does not display "merchant services tab" , "Product and Services tab". I can see only following two tabs.

[image]

How can I enable other tabs that need for development.

Answer (score 2):

create another Sandbox account and make sure to not use the facilitator account. 
When you create the account make sure to create a business account and upgrade it to **pro**. Then use that email and password and login into sandbox.paypal.com and check.